# Aligning long table captions in the list of tables using tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am using the `tocloft` package so that the word Table shows up before the number in the list of tables.  When I do this, the tables with long captions wrap to the next line but are not aligned.  This is the code that I am using.

```
\documentclass [12pt] {article}
\usepackage{times, url}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,footskip=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} 
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }


\begin{document} 

\listoftables  

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}
\caption{Summary Statistics for Structural Housing Characteristics.  Central Kentucky Data, 2000-2011. N=142,164.}
\centering
\footnotesize
\label{table:sumstatsfull}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc} \hline
Variable & Mean & Std. Dev. & Min & Max \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
`

I want the Table to precede the table number but I want the caption to be aligned like it is when the code below is used

`
\documentclass [12pt] {article}
\usepackage{times, url}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,footskip=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} 
%\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }


\begin{document} 

\listoftables  

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}
\caption{Summary Statistics for Structural Housing Characteristics.  Central Kentucky Data, 2000-2011. N=142,164.}
\centering
\footnotesize
\label{table:sumstatsfull}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc} \hline
Variable & Mean & Std. Dev. & Min & Max \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\cfttabfont` is meant to be used to introduce a change of font attributes for the title and the preceding number, so using it to add some string will produce undesired side effects, like the one you noticed.

Add the word "Table" and a space using `\cfttabpresnum` and then use `\cfttabnumwidth` to increase the space reserved for the number:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{times, url}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,footskip=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} 

\newlength\mylen
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{Table }
\settowidth\mylen{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum}
\addtolength\cfttabnumwidth{\mylen}

\begin{document} 

\listoftables  

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\captionsetup{font=normalsize}
\caption{Summary Statistics for Structural Housing Characteristics.  Central Kentucky Data, 2000-2011. N=142,164.}
\centering
\footnotesize
\label{table:sumstatsfull}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc} \hline
Variable & Mean & Std. Dev. & Min & Max \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want "Table" to be flushed to the left margin, add

```
\setlength\cfttabindent{0pt}
```