# Aligning long entries in LOF using tocloft package

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, horizontal-alignment, captions, tocloft

I am facing a problem by left aligning long entries in the LOF using the tocloft package.
Although my TOC for long entries looks perfect and aligned, the LOF is not :( . 
I am using the command

```
 \caption[Short caption]{long caption}
```

to introduce shorter captions in my LOF.

Here an example:

```
Figure 1.1  This is an extremely long long
        long caption not well aligned...........2
Figure 1.2  This is a normal caption............3
```

I needs to be:

```
Figure 1.1  This is an extremely long long
            long caption not well aligned.......2
Figure 1.2  This is a normal caption............3
```

I realized that the problem actually comes due to the fact that I am adding before each Figure number the word "Figure". If I remove this command,

```
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure } % Add the word Figure in LOF
```

then everything is OK in the LOF.

How can I both have it correctly aligned and using the word "Figure"?
I would appreciate any help.

Thank you a lot!
George

Here the entire code I am using, where you can see the problem in the last page (LOF).

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
listof=totoc,
bibliography=totoc,
paper=a4
]{book}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% GRAPHICS PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{textcomp}    
\usepackage{lmodern}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}        % Package for nices LOF and LOT
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{Figure } % Add the word Figure in LOF
%\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{Table }  % Add the word Table in LOT
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\stepcounter{chapter}       % increase chapter counter
\chapter*{Chapter 1 - chapter title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{1 Custom chapter title}    % introduce chapter in the TOC
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Section 1}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{Loooooooooong long long long long long long long long long subsection}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Figure %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \begin{center}
%\includegraphics[width=155mm,clip]{test.eps}
        \end{center}
    \caption[Short caption but toooo loooooooong for the LOF, which does not align it on the left] {\bfseries Part of caption. \textnormal{\textsl{Rest of caption}}} 
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}

\backmatter
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: [Aligning long table captions in the list of tables using tocloft](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123519). As in that question, you are using `\cftfigfont` incorrectly.  The accepted answer shows how to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you Alan. Searched but did not find ! Works perfect